# Send SOAP Request with XML Parameter UTF-8 Java

Tags: java, soap, utf-8

I am looking for an advice here with my problem. I have a SOAP Request in Java with the following code:

```
private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest(String shellType, String filterCondition, 
        Map<String, String> AndySiteToSync) throws Exception {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    createSoapEnvelope(soapMessage, shellType, filterCondition, AndySiteToSync);

    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    soapMessage.saveChanges();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    soapMessage.writeTo(stream);
    return soapMessage;
}
```

I have the following structure on the XML.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:gen="http://general.service.webservices.skire.com">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
  <gen:updateShell>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <gen:shortname>xxx</gen:shortname>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <gen:authcode>xxx</gen:authcode>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <gen:shellType>xxx</gen:shellType>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <gen:shellXML>
     <![CDATA[
    <List_Wrapper>
    <_shell>
       <paraminside>letterwithutf8_ññ</uuu_longitude>
    </_shell>
    </List_Wrapper>
    ]]>
     </gen:shellXML>
</gen:updateShell>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It is working very good with characters without ñ or áéíóú, but when I pass a parameter with ñ for example I see on the result Ã±. When I print the input xml it is showing the XML fine with the correct characters but when I send the request the result is showing the incorrect character (Ã±)

I paste the same input XML in the SOAPUI and the result was good, the ñ characters was introduce fine. The problem is when I send the request using Java.
I assumed it is the encoding of the message. So I added these lines before saveChanges:

```
MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
headers.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");
```

Alse test with:
    headers.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");

These headers are the same as the SOAPUI, with the exception of the "action"
I made sure the headers were ok printing it.

```
for (int iii = 0; iii < headers.getHeader("Content-Type").length; iii++) {
    System.out.println((headers.getHeader("Content-Type"))[iii]);
}
```

and I got the response application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8

This way I am creating the connection:

```
SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(....))
```

SOAPUI

```
POST https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/WebServices HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="urn:xxxxxxx"
Content-Length: 4381
Host: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

Thanks.

===========================================

Thanks to Andreas I did some more testing and the encoding problem was before the SOAP Request, I got the information from a URL in json format with the following code:

```
JSONArray jsonDataFinal = new JSONArray();
JSONArray jsonData = (JSONArray) parser.parse(readUrl(URL));
```

And then:

```
List<Map<String,String>> mergeArray = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
Map<String, String> mergeObj = null;
for (Object o : sitesArray)
{
    if((siteAndy.get("xxxx")) == null) mergeObj.put("xxxx", "");    
    else mergeObj.put("xxxx", ((String) siteAndy.get("xxxx")).trim());
}
```

At what point should I use the utf-8 encoding?

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of `soapMessage.writeTo(stream);`?? You write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then just discard it?? Makes no sense.

Comment: Are you *sure* the encoding issue occurs when writing the soap message and not at some earlier point where you *get* the string values?

Comment: @Andreas forgot to delete those line, you are right. Thanks. And yes I am sure, I print the input XML in a file and it looks correct with the correct values.

Comment: I also did a test with a static input XML and got the same problem.

Comment: You *"print the input XML in a file"*? What encoding did you use for *writing* the file? What encoding did you use when *viewing* the file? Best way to be *sure* the string is correct, is to set a breakpoint and look at the value as Java sees it.

Comment: I edit the question Andreas, I am looking at what point should I use the encoding. Thanks.

Comment: Probably inside `readUrl()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change to this:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

And my problem was fix.

Thanks!!